# Application is working when directly installed using apk, but the same apk which is uploaded to playstore is not working

Tags: android, apk, intentservice

Application is working when directly installed using apk, but the same apk which is uploaded to playstore is not working.

All the features are working except for intent service which is running in background. service is getting destroyed after some interval of time.

I tried using foreground service , but dint work.

MyIntentService.java

```
public class MyIntentService extends IntentService {

private SQLiteDatabase mDB;
private DataBaseOpenHelper mDbHelper;
private Context mContext;
private String mCropNdviValue, mCropName, mCropId, mCropLat="", mCropLong="", mCropCity="", mCropSubCity="", mCropCreatedAt;
private long mRecordId;
private Session mSession;
private boolean isDataUploaded = false;
String threeSecTime="",latestInsertedValue="";



public MyIntentService() {
    super("MyIntentService");
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mContext = MyIntentService.this;
    mDbHelper = new DataBaseOpenHelper(mContext);
    mDB = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    mSession = new Session(mContext);

    Log.e("def", "Service is created");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    while (isDataPresent())
    {
        Log.d("def", "Service starts since data is yet to be uploaded");

        fetchRecordAndUpload();
        Notification notification =
                new Notification.Builder(this)
                        .setContentTitle("Service Status")
                        .setContentText("Service running")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .build();

        startForeground(102, notification);



    }
    Log.d("def", "Service stops since no data is present");
    stopSelf();
}

private boolean isDataPresent() {


    Log.d("def", "isDataPresent is called");
    String[] projection = {
            DataBaseContract.FeedEntry._ID,
    };



    if (mDB != null) {
        Cursor cursor = mDB.query(
                DataBaseContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                projection,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
        );

        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

            return true;

        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    return false;
}

private synchronized void fetchRecordAndUpload() {

    String[] projection = {
            DataBaseContract.FeedEntry._ID,
            DataBaseContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CROP_NDVI_VALUE,
            DataBaseContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CROP_NAME,
            DataBaseContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CROP_ID,
            DataBaseContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CROP_LATITUDE,
            DataBaseContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CROP_LONGITUDE,
            DataBaseContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CROP_CITY,
            DataBaseContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CROP_SUB_LOCALITY,
            DataBaseContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CROP_CREATED_AT
    };

    if (mDB != null) {

        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            cursor = mDB.query(
                    DataBaseContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                    projection,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null
            );


            Log.d("def", "No of records(4) " + cursor.getCount());

            int count = 0;

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {


                Log.e("def", "While loop starts for " + count);

                mRecordId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DataBaseContract.FeedEntry._ID));
                mCropNdviValue = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DataBaseContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CROP_NDVI_VALUE));
                mCropName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DataBaseContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CROP_NAME));
                mCropId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DataBaseContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CROP_ID));

                mCropLat = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DataBaseContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CROP_LATITUDE));
                mCropLong = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DataBaseContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CROP_LONGITUDE));
                mCropCity = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DataBaseContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CROP_CITY));
                mCropSubCity = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DataBaseContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CROP_SUB_LOCALITY));
                mCropCreatedAt = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DataBaseContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CROP_CREATED_AT));
                Log.d("def", "Record id fetched from db- " + mRecordId + " Ndvi data- " + mCropNdviValue);

                uploadToServer();
                isDataUploaded = false;
                while (!isDataUploaded) {
                }
                Log.e("def", "While loop ends for " + count);
                count++;
            }

        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }

    }
}


private void uploadToServer() {


    StringRequest allDealsStringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Session.baseURl + "ndvi_data_time_insert.php?type=1", new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response)
        {
            if (response != null && !response.isEmpty())
            {
                try {

                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    Log.i("response",response);
                    if (jsonObject.getString("Response").equalsIgnoreCase("Success"))
                    {

                        Log.d("def", response);
                        threeSecTime=jsonObject.getString("three_sec_time");
                        mSession.setthreesectime("");
                        if(threeSecTime!=null && threeSecTime!="") {
                            mSession.setthreesectime(threeSecTime);
                        }
                        Log.i("three",threeSecTime);
                        if (deleteRecordFromLocalDB())
                        {
                            Log.d("def", "Record is deleted");
                            isDataUploaded = true;
                        }

                    } else {
                        Log.d("abc", response);

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    Log.d("def", "91 " + e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();


                }

            } else {
                Log.d("def", "99");
                //uploadToServer();
            }


        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            isDataUploaded = true;
            Log.d("def", "56 " + error.getMessage());



        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            Log.d("def", "getParams- " + mSession.getUserId() + " " + mCropNdviValue + " " + mCropCity + " " + mCropLat + " " + mCropLong + " " + mCropSubCity + " " + mCropId + " " + mCropCreatedAt + " " + " " + mSession.getDeviceMacId() + " "+mSession.getthreesectime()+" "+mSession.getpreviousid());
            params.put("user_id", mSession.getUserId());
            params.put("device_id", mSession.getDeviceMacId());
            params.put("ndvi_data", mCropNdviValue.trim());
            if(mCropCity!=null)
            {
                params.put("location", mCropCity.trim());
            }
            else
            {
                params.put("crop_latitude", "");
            }
            if(mCropLat!=null)
            {
                params.put("crop_latitude", mCropLat.trim());
            }else
            {
                params.put("crop_latitude", "");
            }
            if(mCropLong!=null)
            {
                params.put("crop_longitude", mCropLong.trim());
            }else
            {
                params.put("crop_longitude", "");

            }
            if(mCropSubCity!=null)
            {
                params.put("crop_sub_locality", mCropSubCity.trim());
            }else
            {
                params.put("crop_sub_locality", "");

            }
            params.put("crop_id", mCropId.trim());
            params.put("crop_name", mCropName.trim());
            params.put("created_at", mCropCreatedAt.trim());
            params.put("three_update_date",mSession.getthreesectime());





            return params;
        }
    };

    allDealsStringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(20 * 1000, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    SingletonVolley.getInstance(mContext).addToRequestQueue(allDealsStringRequest);

}

private boolean deleteRecordFromLocalDB() {

    String selection = DataBaseContract.FeedEntry._ID + " LIKE ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = {String.valueOf(mRecordId)};
    return (mDB.delete(DataBaseContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs) > 0);
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.e("def", "Service is destroyed");

}
}
```

Comment: How about adding a listener when service has been destroyed then start it again just to make sure.

Comment: Better use Service instead of Intent Service, Intent service destroy itself once finish its task

Comment: i have added some comments in between to trace the flow, everything works fine for some interval of time, after that services will be running but data will not upload to server, when i clear the app from app try and restart it all the data will get uploaded soon after opening the app.

Comment: You might have hardcoded some values may be file location, which you may not find when installed from playstore, check if you have any machine specific hardcoded values.

Comment: Maybe you can share Service code which we look on to for better support.

Comment: shared the intentservice file

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Dinesh Hebbar,

You need to learn about DOZE mode in the Android document which implemented in  All latest os of android, In this feature, you are not accessing your device or any network related operation They will stop your background service uploading or network related task automatically.
https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html

This feature specially implemented for reduce Battery uses,

**Solution**: You can use foreground service.

Comment: thank you for the reply, i'll check it with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Intent service when you are sure that after its job is done it will be destroyed but if you want to do long running tasks then go for Background Service or simple service.
Background Service :
Background service is never destroyed even if user closed your app so you have to stop it yourself or use stopself().
simple service: 
simple Service is destroyed when user close your app then it restart itself.